# (NodeJs, React) ERROR hook - 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, react-router-dom

**Файл CreatePage.js**

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {useHttp} from "../hooks/http.hook"
import {AuthContext} from "../context/AuthContext"
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

export const CreatePage = () => {
    const history = useHistory()
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext)
    const {request} = useHttp()
    const [link, setLink] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        window.M.updateTextFields()
    }, [])

    const pressHandler = async event => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            try {
                const data = await request('/api/link/generate', 'POST', {from: link}, {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`
                })
                history.push(`/detail/${data.link._id}`)

            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col s8 offset-s2" style={{paddingTop: '2rem'}}>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <input
                        placeholder="Вставьте ссылку"
                        id="link"
                        type="text"
                        value={link}
                        onChange={e => setLink(e.target.value)}
                        onKeyPress={pressHandler}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="link">Введите ссылку</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Файл http.hook.js**

```
import {useState, useCallback} from 'react'

export const useHttp = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)

    const request = useCallback(async (url, method = 'GET', body = null, headers = {}) => {
        setLoading(true)
        try {
            if (body) {
                body = JSON.stringify(body)
                headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
            }

            const response = await fetch(url, {method, body, headers})
            const data = await response.json()

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(data.message || 'Что-то пошло не так')
            }

            setLoading(false)

            return data

        } catch (e) {
            setLoading(false)
            setError(e.message)
            throw e
        }
    }, [])

    const clearError = useCallback(() => setError(null), [])

    return { loading, request, error, clearError }
}
```

При запуске проекта всё компилируется без ошибок. На странице CreatePage есть поле для ввода ссылки. При нажатии Enter возникает следующая ошибка:

[image: листинг ошибки]

Посмотрел что передаётся, но так и не понял в чём ошибка:
[image: листинг с выводом]

А должен получать в консоли нечто подобное.
[image: как должно быть]

Answer (score 0):

Проверь файл routes.links.js. У меня в нем была ошибка: вместо link указал link в блоке **router.get**

Ниже приведен верный код:

```js
const { Router } = require('express')
const config = require('config')
const shortid = require('shortid')
const Link = require('../models/Link')
const auth = require('../middleware/auth.middleware')
const router = Router()

router.post('/generate', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const baseUrl = config.get('baseUrl')
        const { from } = req.body

        const code = shortid.generate()

        const existing = await Link.findOne({ from })

        if (existing) {
            return res.json({ link: existing })
        }

        const to = baseUrl + '/t/' + code

        const link = new Link({
            code, to, from, owner: req.user.userId
        })

        await link.save()

        res.status(201).json({ link })
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова" })
    }
})

router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const links = await Link.find({ owner: req.user.userId })
        res.json(links)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова" })
    }
})

router.get('/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const link = await Link.findById(req.params.id)
        res.json(link)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова" })
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.

Comment: aleksandr barakin, благодарю за уточнение. Ответ отредактирован